# using z3 for ALLSAT

Tags: z3

I'm using `Z3` as a black box to find all possible combinations of some real-world objects with C# code like this:

```
while (solver.Check() == Status.SATISFIABLE)

    { 
        SATModel = solver.Model;
        ....
        //invert the Model
        ....
        solver.Assert(InvertedModel)
    }
```

For most of my problems the program is working fine, but now I have a bigger problem, where there would be 8.5E+64 possible combinations without constraints.

I'm starting with some 6000 constraints.

What I observe is that the check action takes less than .02 seconds at the beginning and builds up slowly. After 100000 found solutions it takes already 1 second per turn and after 130000 turns I measure 2 seconds.

Is there an easy way to improve the performance?

Comment: Why don't you use MathSAT then? Its has a better All-SAT than the naive blocking clause.

Answer (score 0):

It's not unreasonable that the solver is taking longer and longer with each constraint. But to make sure it's not some sort of a memory-leak on the C# part, you should check that the time taken in your `while` loop is really in the `Check` part and not in the invert/assert part. If you determine `z3` is the responsible party, perhaps filing it at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues might solicit a better answer from the developers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The times are taken over the check part only and there is no memory leak

Comment: I will not file it as an issue because I think that I'm the one who is missing something.